# Questions about SSH certification

Tags: ssh, certificate

I have some SSH login questions from the client computer to the backup computer.

I have a laptop (client) which should make backups to a Synology via rsync / SSH.
I have read a lot about it in the internet but sometimes you have to do it in that way and sometimes in a other way. So I like to clarify these questions:

- On which computer do I have to create the keys (private / public). On the client or on the backup server?
- Which key do I need to transfer to which server?
- I have created a user "rsync" on the backup server I have to upload the key to this user? Ssh-copy-id rsync@123.123.123.123?
- Should I also create a new (on the client) user for the backup from the client?

I have read about securing the key.

- I want the backup to run automatically without entering a password. Do I have to enter a password when creating the key or not?
- Do I have to delete a key on the client or the backup server after upload this Keys? If so which and where on the client or on the backup server?
- Do I need to give permissions to the key and the folder. If so, on which computer client or backup?
- Should I make a backup of the keys and which privat or public key. To USB stick?

Answer (score 2):

The key-pair should be created on the client, where the *private* key remains.
The *public* key is copied to the server, as you have done with `ssh-copy-id`.

You can create a new user for the backup, but remember it will need to have at least read-access to all the files it needs to backup, so possibly "staff" group or "root" anyway.

The private key should only be readable by the user it belongs to, e.g. `chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa_rsync` as the backup user.

You don't need to make a backup of the keys, as long as you have access to the machines without them, you can just create a new pair when necessary. But it can't hurt regardless.

You can create the keypair without a passphrase, so that `rsync` can use it without asking for one (or you could use an ssh-agent to enter it once and cache it for the duration of your session, but you would always need to be logged in to the *client* for it to work).
If you don't set a passphrase, make sure not to re-use that keypair elsewhere (only for the backup user), and, even better, that it cannot be used to log into your backup server and get a shell, but only to access the rsync daemon.